# Notice API is not working

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I am not able to accept the meeting invitation using the Rest Web Service call.

Facing an issue, if the meeting invitation is rescheduled by the owner before accept/decline by the participant

Error code below

{
    "code":400,
    "text":"Bad Request",
    "cserror":1028,
    "message":"Error processing notice action."
}

Rest url Details

http://domain:port/mail/testuser.nsf/api/calendar/notices/B2B6C5E4B1D4D3DF65257E7C004192C0/action?type=accept

method :- put

Comment: Was a new notice sent out when the owner rescheduled the meeting?

Comment: Yes. it is. Even visible in Lotus notes as well. Email also coming for the same. I tried by accepting with notes client. Its working fine. Only issue with rest url.

Comment: Is the unid in the url referring to the original notice, or the reschedule notice?

Comment: unid found to be same for initial and the rescheduled one.

Comment: Huh? Really? The calendar entry unid doesn't change, but the notices are separate documents and I thought it was requred that all documents must have unique unids. Otherwise replication and many other things would get them confused.